# full-width two columns html

Tags: html, css, width

I want to make 2 full width columns in one box. first column has width: auto and I want second column in 100% minus first column's width, so they can display inline. could someone help me, please?

Comment: use cellpadding attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED
checkout this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cvxr31xo/2/

```
<div id="major">
    <div id="one">Hello</div>
    <div id="two">World</div>
</div>

#major {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#one {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}

#two {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}
```

if you need additional features let me know I will update

Comment: Question states that the first column should have automatic width, you specify 50%.

Comment: I need "width: auto" on the first column so that is not what I am looking for :/

Comment: yes my bad forgot about that writting the code

Comment: That's better! You can get rid of `width: auto` since that is the default anyway. I don't think the `max-width` makes any difference either.

Comment: you mean min-width? it is because he asked about a 100% width two column but the last one is determined by the first one so first one is a certain size and the last one has the rest of the width

Comment: Yeah, meant min-width. http://jsfiddle.net/cvxr31xo/3/ works just as fine without `width: auto` and `min-width`. For a non-floating block element, `width: auto`, the default, makes it occupy all available width without that min-width rule I believe.

Comment: correct but the auto attribute makes it inherit from the major div width I think because I added this attribute in the first incomplete sample I provided because the major div was absent

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're after Table or straight DIVs for this.

```
<div style="width:100%; border:1px solid red;">     
  <div style="display: inline; border: 1px solid black;">Some content</div>
  <div style="display: inline; border: 1px solid black;">Some more content</div>
</div>
```

The second div inside the box div isn't 100% wide, but both divs will expand to content, if that's what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I think you either have to use a table, or mimic one.

**Table:**

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
</table>
```

**Divs**

```
<div style="width: 100; display: table">
    <div style="display: table-cell">col1</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell">col2</div>
</div>
```

Both solutions should make the columns add up to 100% and have automatic widths for both columns. The browser will assign width to them as it sees fit, depending on their contents, so it won't actually first size column 1 independently and then assign column 2 the remaining space, but will find the "best compromise" for both columns.

Edit: The float based solution of @Charlie is actually better in a sense, as it does size the left column independently. However, if the left columns grows too big, the layout may break.

Comment: Curious as to why this answer was so bad it deserves downvoting without comment.

Comment: I know about that issue peter but i think you can easily avoid that by setting a max-width or an overflow attribute to the first column, though I completely forgot how to do it so prefered answer to his current problem for now

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, @Charlie answered very well, perfect answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26757381/3964593

I dont know if you want make it dynamically, or what goal are you trying to achiev, but, still, if the content of one div goes bigger than the other, you should be prepared to handle it.
Like making sure you put a max-width for one or both divs, setting the right amount of height px's or percents, etc. to make it behave right.

Answer (score -1):

try this code.....

```html
<div style="width:100%;">     
  <div style="float:left; width:49.7%; border: 1px solid black;">Some content </div>
  <div style=" float:right; width:49.6%; border: 1px solid black;">Some more content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First column should have auto width, not 49.7%

Comment: else first div width:49.9% and second div width:49.8%